# Are there any alternatives to the OEM muffler for a Volvo XC90?

Tags: exhaust, volvo, muffler

I've been looking for an alternative to the OEM muffler for a Volvo XC90 2.5T AWD.

There are a number of other Volvo vehicles that use the same drivetrain, but not one of the national muffler shops lists an after market muffler.

Is there anything else that will fit with a minimal amount of modification?  The OEM muffler is almost $800.

Comment: The OEM muffler P/N 31201890 is ~$550 as of 09/2016 if you get it from an online Volvo parts store like Volvo Village or Tasca.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the model specific nature of an exhaust system is not the muffler itself but the piping and how it attaches to the underneath of the car.

It has to be sized and bent properly to work its way through from the front to back.

If you are just wanting to replace the muffler and tip, you should be able to purchase those parts individually and get a shop to cut off the old and weld on the new for not that bad of a price.

If you are wanting to do a full "cat back" (everything from the cat to the tip) then a custom one will cost more as the pipes will have to be custom fit.

One downfall to this is you won't know what kind of performance effect it will have on the car as a single muffler will act differently on different model vehicles compared to their OEMs.

Comment: That's what you'd think, but I've talked to 3 different places, and the only option is Volvo muffler.  Not even the muffler from an XC70 will do, apparently.

Comment: I suppose maybe if there is some concern about the emissions system, that a different muffler would cause sensors to go off...